# How can I solve this BVP using mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, boundary-condition-at-infinity, boundary-conditions

I need to solve the following BVP:
$$(g^{-1/3}f'')'+ff''=0$$
$$(g^{-1/3}g')'+0.71fg'=-1.43775g^{-1/3}(f'')^2$$
With the following constraints: 
$$f[0]=0,f'[0]=0,f'[20]=1,g[0]=0.944175,g[20]=1$$
I used the following code:

```
s=NDSolve[{((g[neta]^(-1/3))*f''[neta])'+f[neta] (f^\[Prime]\[Prime]) [neta]==0,((g[neta]^(-1/3))*g'[neta])'+0.71 f[neta] (g^\[Prime])[neta]==-2.025 *0.71 (g^(-1/3))'[neta]((f^\[Prime]\[Prime])[neta])^2,f[0]==0,(f^\[Prime])[0]==0,(f^\[Prime])[20]==1,g[0]==0.9441751033,g[20]==1},{f,g},{neta,0,20}]
```

But I get the error "NDSolve::derarg: "The derivative operator Derivative[1] in... ...should act on the pure function." in Mathematica 8 and "NDSolve::dvnoarg The function f appears with no arguments." in Mathematica online. How should I be solving such a system of ODES for the boundary value problem?

Comment: Just change the derivatives in your ode. For example `(g^(-1/3))'[neta]` should be substituted by `D[(g[neta]^(-1/3)), neta]`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thanks! That seemed to do the trick. However, only mathematica online was able to solve this BVP. Mathematica 8 failed to solve this. Anyways, thanks for the tip.

Comment: It's because the `"Shooting"` method has been silently improved since _v8_. If you have to use _v8_ for the task, then you need to choose initial guess very carefully. There're many related posts in this site, just search `Shooting` here.

Answer (score 1):

All derivatives must be expressed explicitly. After that, the numerical solution is found without any additional conditions, which is surprising

```
eq1 = {f[neta] (f^\[Prime]\[Prime])[neta] - (
     Derivative[1][g][neta] (f^\[Prime]\[Prime])[neta])/(
     3 g[neta]^(4/3)) + 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(f\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", "3", ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[neta]/g[neta]^(1/3) == 
    0, -(Derivative[1][g][neta]^2/(3 g[neta]^(4/3))) + (
      g^\[Prime]\[Prime])[neta]/g[neta]^(1/3) + 
     0.71` f[neta] Derivative[1][g][neta] == -1.4377499999999999`*(-(
       Derivative[1][g][neta]/(3 g[neta]^(4/3))))* (
      f^\[Prime]\[Prime])[neta]^2};
bc = {f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 0, f'[20] == 1, g[0] == 0.9441751033, 
   g[20] == 1};
s = NDSolve[{eq1, bc}, {f, g}, {neta, 0, 20}]

{Plot[Evaluate[{f[x], g[x]} /. s], {x, 0, 20}, PlotLegends -> {f, g}],
  Plot[Evaluate[{g[x]} /. s], {x, 0, 20}, AxesLabel -> {"neta", "g"}, 
  PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: fig1]